# Error of : Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I created a database helper to reduce my code in the laravel framework, and connect to two databases but when I use the function in my helper I receive the error message "Trying to get property of non-object ", this is my helper code:

```
/**
 * This function Used for get Data For Specific Element.
 */
public static function getDataById($dbName,$tableName,$condition,$data)
{
    $stattment=
        DB::connection($dbName)
            ->table($tableName)
            ->select(['*'])
            ->where($condition, $data)
            ->first();
    return $stattment;
}
```

this is my controller function

```
public function all()
{

    $dataView['x']=dBHelper::allData('mysql',
        'products',
        '`status`=? AND `deleted`=?'
        ,array(1,1));

    if(is_object($dataView['x']))
    {
        foreach ($dataView['x'] as $key=>$value):
            $dataView['lang'][$key]=dBHelper::getDataById(
                'mysql2',
                'products',
                'id_product',
                $value->id);
            //var_dump($dataView['lang'][$key]);
        endforeach;
    }

    return view('productss.all',$dataView);
}
```

this is my view

```
<div class="content-wrapper">

    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

    <section class="content-header">

        <h1>

        </h1>

    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->

    <section class="content">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="box box-primary">

                    <div class="box-header with-border">

                        <h3 class="box-title ">Show Products</h3>

                    </div>

                    <!-- /.box-header -->

                    <div class="adminform">



                        <!-- form start -->

                        <table id="all_data" class="table table_for_data table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap tableData" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

                            <thead>

                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>User Name</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                            @if(isset($x)&&is_object($x))
                                @foreach($x as $key=>$value)
                                    <tr>
                                    <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$lang[$key]->name}}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach

                            @else
                                <td>no data found</td>
                            @endif

                            </tbody>

                        </table>

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- /.box -->

            </div>

        </div>

    </section><!-- /.content -->

</div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
```

I receive error when I print

```
<td>{{$lang[$key]->name}}</td>
```

thanks.

Comment: `$lang[$key]` is null in your view. Start debugging in your controller method `all`. Your conditional looks to be preventing some data getting through to your view.

Comment: @adam when i make var dump($dataview['lang'][$key]  it  return data and is not null

Comment: What about `$lang[$key]` in your view?

Comment: It return data as object std and see all data in table pure

Answer (score 0):

As you return `$dataView` to the View, you should:

```
@if(isset($dataView['x']) && is_object($dataView['x']))
    @foreach($dataView['x'] as $key=>$value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value['lang'][$key]->name}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach

@else
    <td>no data found</td>
@endif
```

Hope this helps. On the other hand, *shortcuts* like yours make it hard to debug, or expand on a future date. It is better to build out he Models and their relationships, thus making use of Laravel's native ORM. It takes more time but will dramatically speed up the production process of your app.